# Removing old users with sudo in terminal

Tags: terminal, user-account

Awhile ago, I removed a former staff account from a mac mini but kept the home folder in users, using the regular user management UI in system preferences. A virus scan came up with multiple threats from that directory so I opted to `su` to admin and then sudo remove the entire directory.

Is this wrong, to remove a user in this way?

Comment: Did you run the virus scan again?

Comment: I'm still removing the account. I will then run the scan again. The scan was unable to remove the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you removed the user account in System Preferences → Users & Groups, opting to leave the folder as is, the folder is completely disassociated with any account management system in macOS — at this point, it's just a folder. You can remove this folder, or perform any other actions to it, like you would any other folder on the system.